# Batch file to list all folders in a directory and output to txt with

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to create a batch file to parse a directory Z:\ (not including sub folders) which is a mapped network drive to give all folders that name includes "COMPANY_*" and output those folder names with the the full path to a text file.

The text file will be saved to a program folder location which is referenced when you run the program.

For example

Dir:

- Z:\Company_001
- Z:\def
- Z:\Comapny_002
- Z:\Company_101

Text file:

- Z:\Company_001
- Z:\Company_002
- Z:\Company_101

I started to have a go but dont know what I am doing and need to run this batch on 10 computers so do not want to cause any problems.

```
dir "Z:\" /b >d:\test.txt
FOR /F "delims=" %%a in (test.txt) do @echo Z:\%%a>>output.txt
del "d:\test.txt"
start C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe "d:\output.txt"
pause
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
cd Z:\
for /D %%A IN ("COMPANY_*") DO echo "Z:\%%A">>D:\output.txt
```

You can add a call to open the file with notepad if you want to. What you have now would work.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you can get the folders that you want with no intermediate filtering:

```
dir Z:\Company_* /b /a:d >output.txt
```

Comment: This is a very valid solution and is cleaner. The only reason I suggested doing a "for" loop is because OP wanted the full path printed to file (which is really pretty trivial information when no subfolders are involved)